Django save override only if anything other than a single field is updated?
I realize a version of this has been asked and answered, but I believe my question is slightly different enough where I could not find an answer.
I have a model with a version that I want to increment by 1 any time the object is updated/saved. But I only want to increment the version if any field values were changed other than the program. Put another way, a training's version should not be incremented if the only change was adding or removing a program. There are times where the program will be changed along with other fields, in which case it should increment.
models.py
class Training(BaseTeamModel): 
    title = models.CharField("Title",max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)
    program = models.ManyToManyField(Program,related_name='programs')
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # How to increment the version only if fields were changed
        # other than program.
        self.version = self.version + 1
        super(Training, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

I could compare each value with the previous value for each field, but that is not scalable and would result in some messy models.
